# Intellij Idea. I cannot see javadoc in source code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Before moving to Ubuntu I used IntelliJ on Windows. When I used ctrl + left click IDE showed me implementation with comment description above each method and class. But now implementation is shown without comments. How can I set that?

Comment: I noticed that ctrl + click leads to the decompilation of .class file. Does it have to do with it? I don't remember whether it was a decompilation on Windows. Maybe I have to set the Intellij to show .java file? Can you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the class you're looking at also has sources attached, either through the IDE or through your dependency manager.  If there are no sources available, then all you can receive is the decompiled version.

You will have to attach sources to the library you wish if you want to see the full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared it up. The point was that I installed OpenJDK from default set Ubuntu repositories that doesn't have sources attached. The solution was to install official Oracle JDK like I did before. To do it, add Oracle's repository to your system and install jdk: https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/

Comment: You could have installed the sources from the repos as well

Comment: yes how do you install the openjdk docs from the repo? i don't want to use the oracle jdk.